# Bind IS NULL or NULL when using PHP PDO and MySql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How can I bind `NULL` in the following scenario. No matter what I do, I can't get it to work.

```
if ($type == 1) {
    $self   = 'NULL';
    $parent = 'NULL';
}

$findThis = $conn->prepare('select count(id) as exists from table where id = :id and self = :self and parent = :parent';

$findThis->execute(array(
    ":id"     => $id,
    ":self"   => $self,
    ":parent" => $parent
));
```

Comment: did you try something like `parent IS NULL`

Comment: If you need to use nulls, you use `$stmt->bindValue(':placeholder', null, PDO::PARAM_NULL);`. If you can avoid using nulls, use SQL's `IS NULL` etc.

Comment: @N.B. first one obviously won't work.

Comment: @YourCommonSense - well feel free to correct if it's wrong, so people can see what's correct and what isn't, this way we're left hanging :)

Comment: The reason I wrote the comment was to show *how* to use null values in queries (you might want to insert a null). That's why it's a comment and not an answer. Naturally, since answers tackle the problem properly - there was no need to repeat the same. Also, I'll leave the comment there just in case someone stumbles upon this and for some odd reason can't determine how to handle null values upon inserting. Answers are sufficient, the example in my comment is **wrong** for this particular usage scenario and I'll leave it in so people don't make the same mistake.

Comment: Ok, it's entirely up to you.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE. By an by I have learned that all can be done in one query

```
$sql = 'select 1 from table where id = ? and self <=> ? and parent <=> ?';
$stm = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute([$id,$self,$parent]);
$exists = $stm->fetchColumn();
```

<s>You have to amend your query as well.</s>

```
$sql = 'select count(id) as exists from table where id = ? and ';

if ($type == 1) {
    $sql .= 'self IS NULL and parent IS NULL'
    $data = [$id];
} else {
    $sql .= 'self = ? and parent = ?';
    $data = [$id,$self,$parent];
}
$stm = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

For null values, you have to use `IS NULL` in the sql instead.