# PHP PDO 'WHERE' statement working for null and not-null values

Tags: php, sql, pdo, null, isnull

Let's have 3 records in the database:

```
id | name  |  value
---|-------|--------
1  | 'xxx' | 'zzz'
2  |  null | 'aaa'
3  | 'yyy' | 'bbb'
```

There is a simple data query I want to perform. It is easy to find out if the following object is in database:

```
name  = 'yyy'
value = 'bbb'
```

But what about the others? They contain null values. Is there any way to tell PDO to use `WHERE name IS NULL` or `WHERE value IS NULL` when the respective field is actually `null`? I have seen similar functionality in several frameworks but I do not know how to do this directly in PDO. Is it even possible or we have to check whether the values are null and build the query according to it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bind IS NULL or NULL when using PHP PDO and MySql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18735955/bind-is-null-or-null-when-using-php-pdo-and-mysql)

Comment: Have you tried? You can just add in the WHERE clause just like you have it. What's your full query?

Comment: I have tried. This does not work: `$pdo->query('select id from my_table where name=? and value=?', array(null, 'aaa'));`

Comment: @aynber The problem is that `WHERE column = NULL` is incorrect. It's called `WHERE column IS NULL`. `WHERE column IS 'value'` is incorrect as well though, so that's why OP is asking, as you can't just bind NULL.

Comment: Ah. No. I was thinking adding "OR name IS NULL" into the query.

Comment: @Pavel you can use the `<=>` operator which works with nulls as well. Only need to bind value dynamically with `PARAM_TYPE_NULL`.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Thanks, but that's exactly my question. Because `column = NULL` does not work, what is the best solution?

Comment: @aynber That would work but I do not want to accept both possibilities. As an example, if I query `name = kkk`, `value = aaa`, your suggestion would return the second row, but it is obviously incorrect.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thanks, could you write a comprehensive example, as an answer? I think it is not only me who would be happy to see it how exactly it works.

Comment: Would you please try of your own? Ten you can erite an answer yourself and I'd be happy to upvote it

Comment: @YourCommonSense I have tried, but with no success:
    `$query = $this->pdo->prepare('select my_value from my_table where name <=> :name');  
    $query->bindParam(':name', $myValueInPhp, PDO::PARAM_NULL);  
    $name = $query->fetchColumn();` Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @YourCommonSense And by the way, PARAM_TYPE_NULL does not exist in PHP.

Comment: It worked for me. What actually doesn't work for you?

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the documentation where <=> is described?